# Mozilla addon-sdk - How do I mask Umlaut in de-DE.properties?

Tags: utf-8, localization, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I would like to offer my add-on in 2 different languages,
so I added a folder named 'locale' with en-US.properties and de-DE.properties in it.
For the German umlaute ä, ö, ü and for the letter ß I tried different encodings, none
of them working. Is there a way to mask them?
And, btw, is it slowing the add-on down considerably working with data-attributes for
every single text-node in the html-files of the addon-panels?

Comment: It seems that all I had to do was 'Convert to UTF-8 without BOM' inside in the editor (in Notepad++ under 'Encoding').

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility.

You can use:

```
&Auml; = Ä
&Uuml; = Ü
&Ouml; = Ö

&auml; = ä
&uuml; = ü
&ouml; = ö
```

For german ß (called eszett) use

```
&szlig; = ß
```